# Grails + MongoDB: what's a replacement for isNull criteria?

Tags: grails, mongodb

I'm testing a Grails model with MongoDB (mongodb plugin 1.0-M4)

I have a Category object that can have parent Category.

MongoDB doesn't support IsNull in criteria, so I can no longer do this to find parentless Categories:

```
Category.createCriteria().get {
    isNull('parent')
}
```

How *do* you find null HasOne relationships with MongoDB in Grails?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using any MongoDB plugin for Grails?

Comment: is it work with eq('parent', null)

Comment: @Hoang-long I'm using mongodb plugin 1.0-M4

Comment: @Medrod: post your comment as an answer.  It works, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Category.createCriteria().get {
    eq('parent', null)
}
```